# Firefox OS simulator - call to Function() blocked by CSP

Tags: javascript, cordova, firefox-os

I'm running the `Firefox OS v2.2` simulator on my `Firefox 42.0`.
My app was running fine on it some months ago, but now I get this error and it refers to `handlebars.js`.

It says: `Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("script-src app://50d74c3c-64ca-402e-9d0a-47f0cb9f378c"). handlebars-v4.0.5.js:3562:0` and the message is `call to Function() blocked by CSP`.

I use `cordova 5.4.1`, `require-js`, `handlebars 4.0.5` and other js plugins.

Could it be related to my Firefox main browser? I mean, if I edit the `about:config` menu and change `security.csp.enable` to `false` could it be helpful?

Any advice for this problem?

Thanks

**edit**:

here is the first lines of my `index.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

So I have no `Content-Security-Policy` tag in my `index.html`.

Comment: What does your Content Security Policy meta tag look like?

Comment: @SimonPrickett Where do I have to check it?

Comment: Should be in the head in your index.html

Comment: @SimonPrickett, ok see my edit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSP is enforced if your app type is privileged. Check your app type in your app manifest, and make sure it's not privileged if you don't need to use special permissions. Otherwise, if you need a privileged app, you have to get rid of the CSP violations in your code and also in the libraries you use. I've had a hard time with CSP since in my app I wanted to use special permissions due to camera access (MozCameras). I simply couldn't make my app work with require.js, so I got rid of it, and now everything works fine.

Comment: Well I just need permissions for notifications, nothing more. How can I make my app not privileged in the manifest? Also my problems seem to refer to `handlebars.js` and I don't know why

Comment: ok, I just solved by removing the `"type": "privileged"` in my manifest, but the notification don't work.

Comment: The following web page says you don't need to be a privileged app to use notifications, but you still need to define the permission in your app manifest. Check if you defined that properly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API